# Firebase: set data when user navigates away from page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if it's possible to set some data in a firebase database when the user navigates away from a page. I know about window.onbeforeunload but that doesn't seem to work because the firebase call is canceled right after this method is called (because the user navigates away). Or does it?

The use-case is this: I'm building a chat app where I keep track of users in a chatroom. So I need to know when a user leaves that chat room - and one of the ways the user can leave it is by navigating away or closing the browser window.

The workaround would be to have each user update a timestamp with an interval (say, 10 seconds) and handle it on the client side (if the timestamp of a user is older than 10 seconds than he must be away). But this would create a lot of overhead network traffic and doesn't seem to be very efficient..?

PS: I'm targetting Chrome (desktop and mobile) but it would be nice if we could find a solution that works cross-browser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for onDisconnect()

Here you can find how to ue it
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works

Basically is a Firebase event that gets called when a user gets disconnected

It can be used to show in a chat group which users are still active and which not..etc